# How to change "base" HEAD tag, from php?

Tags: php, html, css

From php, I make a POST request which returns in HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/footer.css">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

the problem is, the result looks like it has no CSS, because it tries to load from [www.mysite.com/css/footer.css](http://www.mysite.com/css/footer.css). But I did to "externalsite.com", and if that HTML is loaded on the other site, it looks fine. If I edit the result HTML and add "base" meta, it works, but I dont think editing-and-replacing-HTML-code direct way is ok.

Comment: Take a step back… Why isn't the CSS available there exactly?

Comment: It seems to be an XY issue... You probably don't want to add a base tag in this case cause a base tag will "override" any relative URL's. If your goal is to use relative URL's for CSS  (which is probably better) then make the resource available on whatever path it is expected to be. If your goal is to use an absolute URL to another CDN, then use an absolute URL.

Comment: yea, I took a step back.... I did a form-submit instead

Answer (score 1):

I think, most likely, you have access to resources on one page with both relative paths (`/css/footer.css`) and with the full domain name (`www.mysite.com/css/footer.css`) of the site, and in this case XSS protection is triggered in the browser. When you specify the `base` tag, the browser considers that all loaded resources with relative paths should be downloaded only from the site specified in this tag, and ignored with the full domain name, this is considered safe and the protection does not work.